# Sass changes visible when compiled locally but don't show up when uploaded to server

Tags: wordpress, sass, prepros

I am using Prepros.io to make changes to sass based Wordpress theme. My issue is the changes I'm making a working locally but when I uploaded the files to the server, the css changes I made don't show up.

Do I need to export the files before uploading them ? Any ideas why this would work locally but not on the live server?

Comment: You local installation is most probably using an automated build process, where it autoruns the SASS compilation to CSS when a file changes.

Comment: Yes that's correct, it does do that. Any ideas what I need to do to ensure I can push it to the server correctly?